# Lots of broken spokes on one bike, with different wheels

Tags: hub, rims, spokes

I have a commuting bike I've had for a few years, and as long as I've had it it's frequently broken spokes on the front wheel. Eventually I got sick of replacing them, put it down to a bad wheel, and replaced it with another wheel I had lying around. This second wheel is a decent Mavic touring rim on a Shimano Deore hub, and it's done a couple of years of trouble free service on a previous bike.
Anyway, within a couple of months I got my first broken spoke and now it's the same pattern as before. Each time I replace I true the wheel up carefully and then check it again after a couple of days.

Over the last 20 odd years on several bikes I remember very few broken spokes- once on a loaded tourer, and maybe one or two MTBing.

So my question is this: Is there anything about a particular bike that might cause a lot of broken spokes- maybe forks slightly out of true or something? 
It's a single speed with a reasonably high gear (45x16) and I am frequently out of the saddle but I can't think this would be any more or an issue than climbing hills on my road bike.

UPDATE

So a month or so ago I broke 3 spokes in 3 rides, and ran out of patience. After letting the bike sit in a corner for a bit I found a cheap replacement fork and swapped it over. A couple of weeks later and everything is good, so at the moment it looks like that was the problem- early days yet though I suppose, as it took a while for the original setup to start popping spokes and now the wheel might have a few dodgy ones in it.

Thanks for all the suggestions!

Comment: Perhaps your fork is crooked, putting uneven stress or strain on the wheel? Without a wheel in it, do both arms of the fork match up?

Comment: Here's a Sheldon Brown page with instructions for checking fork alignment http://sheldonbrown.com/forkend-alignment.html   Is the frame an MTB? Do you know if the fork is original?  Where are the spokes breaking? I'm wondering if the fork rake or length could be mismatched with the frame.

Comment: Fork is original, I'll have to have a closer look at the fork alignment. They spokes always go at the hub, doesn't seem to be a pattern for which side.

Comment: Another thing to check is the trueness of the wheel and the tension of the spokes. Are they all uniformly under the proper tension? Are some so loose that you could, with fingers only, turn the spoke nipples enough to loosen them? The last step in wheelbuilding is a strain-relief step where you squeeze pairs of spokes with your hand-- if any are loose again after that, they need to be re-adjusted.

Comment: Is there a rack or fenders on the front of the bike? Dyno?

Comment: I'm going to ask a basic question, don't get offended. How much do you weight or at least have you gained weight in the past few years? A few extra pounds can make a difference on the reliability of your spokes. How many spokes are in your front wheel?

Comment: Do note that spokes have a limited (though substantial) lifetime, and any wheel will begin to experience spoke failure after some 10s of thousands of miles.  And I have to imagine that riding out of the saddle on a fixie can place more stress on front spokes than more traditional riding.

Comment: I probably weigh about 80kg- I have put on a bit of weight lately but I'd like to think I'm not heavy enough for it to be an issue!

Comment: Re spoke age, I have far older wheels where it hasn't been a problem so I'm inclined to think that's not the issue. I have been thinking more lately about extra stresses from riding SS  (not fixed) though.

Comment: Wheel is either 32 or 36 spoke- it's certainly not a flashy low spoke count job.

Comment: One assumes that you would have said by now if this is a disk brake wheel vs rim brakes.

Comment: Original wheel was disc compatible but also had a braking surface and I only ever used it with V brakes. The disc thing was one of the things that made me wonder if it was a wheel issue. Replacement wheel is rim only.

Comment: You mention that you've been repairing the wheels yourself. Try having a good wheelbuilder (not necessarily your LBS) take a look at them.

Comment: I'm wondering if the brakes could somehow be at fault.  Conceivably one side of the brakes could be somehow frozen so that when you brake it presses only on one side of the rim, stressing the spokes on that side.

Answer (score 2):

- Are your brakes properly aligned? If they're off-center, every time you brake you'll generate a lateral force on the wheel that spokes absolutely *hate*.
- How do you store your bicycles? Do they live in the garage or in the living room? If you live near the beach, the salt can cause corrosion and weaken the components.
- Like the comments said, check the fork alignment. Since you stated that you had a wheel lying around that had never been a problem before mounting it on this particular bike, it leads me to think that there is something wrong with the current bike.

Comment: Brakes are OK, bike lives in flat, and I'm nowhere near the sea! Like you, it was the problems with the second wheel that started me wondering if it could be something about the bike.

Comment: I wonder if there is something on your commute route that is causing the rims to get slightly bent. (Train tracks ?). Repeated broken spokes almost always means a bent rim.